# rebind properties in model, emberjs

Tags: data-binding, ember.js

I have just started to use ember.js. I have two models in my application. One that holds data and one that holds this data edited by user. I bind them using one-way binding.

```
App.ViewModel = Ember.Object.create({
  title:'title',
  text:'text',
)};

App.EditModel = Ember.Object.create({
  titleBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.ViewModel.title'),
  textBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.ViewModel.text'),
)};
```

I let a user edit the data in EditModel model. But if the user discard the changes I want to be able to set the values back to the state before editing, ie. to the values in ViewModel.

Is there a way to rebind those properties? Or to manualy rise change event on properties in ViewModel so EditModel gets updated? Or any other approach to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom Mixin which handles the reset for a model, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/CjB4S/

```js
App.Editable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    startEditing: function() {
        var propertyNames = this.get('propertyNames');
        var props = this.getProperties.apply(this, propertyNames);
        this.set('origProps', props);
    },
    reset: function() {
        var props = this.get('origProps');
        Ember.setProperties(this, props);
    }
});


App.myModel = Ember.Object.create(App.Editable, {
    propertyNames: ['title', 'text'],
    title: 'le title',
    text: 'le text'
});
```

And later in the views you just invoke the `startEditing` when you want to take a snapshot of the current values and `reset` when you want to reset to the previous snapshot of the values.

Comment: Look great! We could even imagine some kind of automation of this by observing model's states, when using ember-data models.

Comment: I'd like to add that the specification of propertyNames array on the model has been of separate use to me in generating clean objects to send to the server. Nice touch